# PHP for loop vs C for loop

Tags: php, c++, performance, for-loop

It is known that to do following in PHP is bad idea (because `count ($array)` will be called on every iteration which can seriously slow down script execution):

```
<?php
for ( $i = 0; $i < count ($array); ++$i )
{
   // Code here;
}
```

Instead one should calculate condition outside of the loop:

```
<?php
$a = count ($array);

for ( $i = 0; $i < $a; ++$i )
{
   // Code here;
}
```

I am new to compiled languages so I got a question:

**Does the same rule applies to compiled languages like C and C++ for example?**

Let's say I want to iterate vector in C++. Should I avoid such for loop or it is fine?

```
for ( int i = 0; i < vector.size(); ++i )
{
    // Code here
}
```

If this is not an issue in compiled languages - is it because compiler takes care for this and optimizes executable file or there is another reason behind that?

Comment: there is still a small performance hit, but in most cases people will use iterators instead. for Size() performance see: stackoverflow.com/questions/8469218/… depending on the implementation it could be done in constant time (i.e. keeping track of the size)

Comment: "Instead one should calculate condition outside of the loop": Well actually in php it is more idiomatic to use `foreach` for iterating an array. And in C++ it is more idiomatic to use iterators. Neither has the problem you are talking about.

Comment: @Tim, your are right and thank you for your opinion. But my question was not about "should `for` or `foreach` loop be used", but about _if I would use_ **for loop** - then how I do it.

Comment: I understood it. My answer was "don't do it". That is IMO the only useful answer to this question. Some of the others have gone into more detail in the manner you likely wanted. This is a micro-optimization issue. Program idiomatically and clearly for the language you are writing in unless it has a performance problem. Then profile your code. I don't bet the problem will be something like this nine times out of ten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question comes down to "does the compiler know the answer at compile time"?

In the case you gave, the answer is "no". Since it is possible to change the size of the vector inside the loop it should get evaluated every time (but it's pretty fast since it's not counting one at a time).

Code like this:

```
int myArray[20];
for(int ii = 0; ii < sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(*myArray); ii++) {
```

will in fact evaluate `sizeof` at compile time, and be very marginally more efficient because of this. Note - you need the whole expression since `sizeof(myArray)` by itself will return `80` in this case (where an `int` is four bytes). The advantage of using `sizeof(*myArray)` is that if you change your mind about the type of `myArray`, this line of code doesn't break…

And the fact that you are using a division here doesn't slow down execution, since it's all done during compile time (only once).

To re-iterate what I said in my comment: in this instance, the version you are proposing, whilst evaluating the size of the vector on each iteration, is really not a problem. It is extremely unlikely that you could see a performance difference in all but the tightest loops. Don't fall into [the trap of micro-optimization](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html)

Here is a simple timing example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
  vector<int> testVector(200);
  int ii, jj;
  register int ss;
  time_t startT, endT;

  // case 1: using a constant for loop condition
  startT = clock();
  for(ii = 0; ii < 100000; ii++) {
    for(jj = 0; jj < 200; jj++) {
      testVector[jj] = ii - jj;
    }
  }
  endT = clock();
  printf("using constant: elapsed time: %.2f ms\n", (endT - startT) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

  // case 2: using size():
  startT = clock();
  for(ii = 0; ii < 100000; ii++) {
    for(jj = 0; jj < testVector.size(); jj++) {
      testVector[jj] = ii - jj;
    }
  }
  endT = clock();
  printf("using size: elapsed time: %.2f ms\n", (endT - startT) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

  // case 3: single call to size():
  startT = clock();
  ss = testVector.size();
  for(ii = 0; ii < 100000; ii++) {
    for(jj = 0; jj < ss; jj++) {
      testVector[jj] = ii - jj;
    }
  }
  endT = clock();
  printf("with size out of loop: elapsed time: %.2f ms\n", (endT - startT) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

This gives the following result:

```
using constant: elapsed time: 162.47 ms
using size: elapsed time: 277.02 ms
with size out of loop: elapsed time: 241.01 ms
```

As you can see, there *is* a finite amount of time associated with looking up the size of the vector in every loop; but it is about 100 ms for 20,000,000 calls, or 5 ns per call. That sounds about right; as you can see, when your loop is tight enough it is measurable; but it is unlikely to be of practical significance in most "real" code instances (where you are likely to do more in your loop). As you can also see, just moving the call to `size` out of the loop doest help much - using a constant vs a variable is a bigger difference.

Comment: With C++11 you can use `std::extent<decltype(myArray)>::value` instead to get the number of array elements

Comment: @Praetorian Or `std::distance(begin(myArray),end(myArray))` which should work for most container types (only recommended for random access containers), so switching to `std::vector` is no problem.

Comment: @leemes That works, but you've changed a compile time evaluation to a runtime function call.

Comment: The compiler can inline runtime functions too.

Comment: @Floris, what if I am using `vector`? I can't declare array with known size, because I do not know how many elements will come in there. Can I still do `sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(*myArray)` but with vector?

Comment: No you can't, sorry. `sizeof` is a compiler directive - it can only evaluate an object whose size is known at compile time. Note that the various ways to get the size of a vector are in fact very fast (not the same as a constant, but plenty fast). My advice to you: "don't worry be happy". There is always the risk of [micro-optimization](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html). Worry about the big stuff. This isn't it.

Comment: @Floris, I wish I could accept your answer as well. I like how did you narrow it down to `The question comes down to "does the compiler know the answer at compile time"?`

Comment: @Floris, you got it. Excellent elaboration.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of, a for loop can be interpreted like thus in C++:

```
{
    int i = 0; // initializer
    while(i < vector.size()){
         // loop body
         ++i; // increment
    }
}
```

So `size` IS called each increment, it's just not very heavy

Since you're using a `vector` a better way is to use iterators for safety anyway:

```
for(auto iter = vector.begin(), end = vector.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
{
}
```

Note that I'm initializing the iterators only once in the initialization and not comparing to `.end()` which could be expensive for some container types, although with `vector` it would be no different than calling `size` in terms of effect.

or a new C++11 loop

```
for(auto & i: vector){
}
```

This is really just syntactic sugar for the the iterator example above

To be honest in **C++ worrying about it a micro-optimization... and should be avoided in favor of readability.** Unlike an interpreted language the compiler can do a lot to fix small performance mistakes. In the (paraphrased) words of the STL maintainer at Microsoft *"Don't 'help' the compiler, you're making things worse"*

Comment: Comparing to `.end()` should be just about as expensive as calling `.size()`, or maybe even less so because the latter can involve a subtraction while the former won't. In any case, like you've mentioned, these trivialities are something you shouldn't worry about in most cases. And there's no reason a compiler cannot stick constants in place of both function calls if it can prove that the vector is not being modified within the loop.

Comment: aye, particularly if you use `cend` instead of `end`. I've fixed my answer to reflect reality which is that `end` can be expensive under some circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same. The compiler or interpreter cannot know if the size will be changed throughout the loop, or not.

However, if you know you will not change the size - you surely can calculate the variable outside the loop, same as in PHP.