# Should the loop limit be evaluated or stored?

Tags: c++, optimization

In C++, is it faster to store the limit of a loop in a variable than evaluating the value?

For example:

Is it a slower approach to use

```
for(int i=0; i<n*n+2*n; ++i)
{ .... }
```

than doing the following?

```
for(int i=0, limit=n*n+2*n; i<limit; ++i)
{ .... }
```

For clarity, assume that `n` is some given variable that remains unchanged during the course of the loop.

Comment: Well.. measure it.

Comment: How? Please explain as I am a newbie.

Comment: I think we need to see a bit more of the code. How is `limit` related to the loop?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. This is a nice question now.

Comment: This is really the wrong question to ask. If you're having speed problems, this is probably the *last* place you'd look to improve. Rule number one of optimization: don't optimize unless it's too slow for your needs. (If you don't know whether it's too slow for your needs, you're not ready to optimize.) Now, if you're interested in if the *behavior* differs between the two, that could potentially affect the logic of your program.

Comment: How to benchmark a program is computer & operating system specific. Read more about [profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29). On Linux, you might use the [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) command. Be sure to enable [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) when compiling (e.g. compile with `g++ -Wall -O2` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...)

Comment: [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20820094/1418463) to a similar question

Comment: I don't think there's anything *wrong* in asking whether the calculations in the exit condition are slower than a manually cached counterpart. While in real codes this might virtually never be a problem, it is nevertheless a legitimate curiosity. Telling someone "this is really the wrong question to ask" is ignoring the theoretical curiosity aspect of programming, and reducing everything to "what matters in practice".

Answer (score 21):

If `n` is a globally declared non-`volatile` variable, then the behaviour of

`for (int i = 0; i < n * n + 2 * n; ++i)`

is *unspecified*. A compiler is allowed to optimise `n * n + 2 * n` to be evaluated once even if another thread modifies `n`. Furthermore, if another thread is able to modify `n`, then you should take steps to avoid the potential for simultaneous read and writes of `n` (the behaviour of which is *undefined*). Consider using `std::atomic<int>` as the type for `n`.

So really it's appropriate to introduce `limit` anyway if you want the stopping condition to be dependent on the value of `n` observable when program control reaches the `for` loop,  irrespective of any performance considerations. Consider therefore

`for (int i = 0, limit = n * n + 2 * n; i < limit; ++i)`

which has the advantage that the scope of `limit` doesn't leak into the surrounding statements.

But if you are able to, you could always run the loop backwards:

`for (int i = n * n + 2 * n - 1; i >= 0; --i)`

Be *very* careful though with `unsigned` types if you adopt that idea.

Comment: "The behaviour is unspecified" does not follow from "a compiler is allowed to optimize... even if another thread modifies `n`." If no other thread modifies `n`, the behaviour is well defined. If another thread does modify `n`, then the behaviour is undefined, and the introduction of `limit` does not fix that.

Comment: If `n` is an ordinary global variable, a compiler would be allowed to cache its value if it can see that there is nothing in the loop that could change it, but I know of nothing in the Standard that would allow such caching if the loop calls outside code or writes to an `int*` of unknown provenance which is not `restrict` qualified.

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't matter outside of a hot spot. I mean - yes, calculating the value only once will be faster in debug with no compiler optimizations, and at least as fast in release. But it usually doesn't matter. Do it the way that is easier to write, to read and to maintain. Let me quote Donald Knuth's famous words:

> The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time
>   worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times;
>   premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of
>   it) in programming.

Having said that, I prefer this way since recently:

```
for (int i = 0, upperBound = n*n + 2*n /*or n*(n + 2)*/; i < upperBound; ++i)
{
}
```

This way the scope of `upperBound` is limited to the `for` statement itself and doesn't bleed into the outer scope where it's not needed.

Comment: It's unclear how Knuths' quote matters here. Why should this micro-optimization be evil?

Comment: @Walter: any micro-optimization is evil when it's unnecessary. This kind of questions is _exactly_ what Knuth was talking about.

Comment: I agree to some degree with your comment (though I still dislike the word *evil*, which implies divious intent -- Knuth spoke of the *root of evil*). However, it was unclear from the question whether or not the optimization was unnecessary.

Comment: @Walter: good catch with the semantics :) I think if the OP knew the optimization is necessary, he'd tell us. Moreover, he wouldn't need to ask the question in the first place. By that reasoning, it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Glad to see a sane answer. @Walter "micro-optimizations" are almost *always* unnecessary, and they almost *always* make your code worse from the perspective of a human trying to read it.

Comment: Let's say n=50000... Then without this optimisation, will performance not get affected?

Comment: Why does the value of n matter?

Comment: @Walter: Don't do what Knuth says just because Knuth said it. Develop your own reasons. If I can give you a clue what a good reason is: *lots* of people on this site ask if "X is slower than Y" when either X or Y consumes less than 0.1% of execution time. That's like asking if a new car will be faster if it has white paint or black, or asking if you can lose weight by getting a haircut.

Comment: Some of the discussion can be settled when placing the quote by D. Knuth into its original context, as written in his article *Structured programming with goto statements*: *"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. **Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%**. A good programmer will not be lulled into complacency by such reasoning, he will be wise to look carefully at the critical code; but only after that code has been identified."* (Emphasis by me. Maybe we are talking about these 3% here...)

Comment: And by the way: I, personally, consider the style of adding another variable in the loop as *far* less readable than a variable that is declared before the loop (even though this variable then has a scope that is larger than necessary). But this is just an opinion.

Comment: @Marco13: I find it more readable, as well as not polluting the outer scope.

Comment: @Marco13: I find irksome the attitude by some compiler makers that programmers should leave the job of optimization to the compiler, even though such an attitude makes code less portable than it would be if programmers can make optimizations themselves.

Comment: @supercat It's tricky. As shown in the other answer: The `for(int i=0; i<n*n;...)` and the `for (int i=0,bound=n*n; i<bound;...)` approach might be **different programs**, with different behaviors (depending on sth. like a `volatile`). Whether or not one initializes the `bound` **in** the loop or **before** the loop may be subjective, but in both cases, it makes clear that the bound is **not** *supposed* to change in the loop. This is good. (BTW: I'm at home in the Java world, where such attempts to "optimize" things are usually ridiculous: The JIT does a *remarkably* good job at optimizing)

Comment: @Marco13: I sometimes wish C had a form of declaration that would include an identifier and an expression and tell the compiler that it may evaluate the expression at any time within the lifetime of the identifier, and have the identifier yield any value that expression could yield at any such time.  If a compiler had a register available, it could cache the value of the expression in the register.  If, however, the cost of keeping the variable (due to register spillage or whatever) would exceed the cost of computing it on demand, a compiler could opt to do the latter instead.

Comment: @Marco13: Applying such a concept to the loop bounds would mean that in cases where copying it to a separate variable would improve performance, a compiler could do so [even if it wouldn't be able to determine--absent the directive--that it was "safe"], but in cases where it would be more efficient to compute the value on demand a compiler could do that.  The programmer will often know more than the compiler about what would be "safe"; the compiler will know more than the programmer about what would be efficient.  Both pieces of information are often needed to make optimal decisions.

Comment: @supercat To some extent, I agree on the "safe vs. efficient" part. Beyond that, I'm not sure whether I understood this in all depth. There e.g. are `volatile` and `register` keywords, but don't know their *exact* meaning (although I think that `register` is basically ignored nowadays). But I want to emphasize that the step from code to instructions is *intimidatingly complex*. Even *starting* to read about things like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol , memory models with all their read/write fences etc. will show that "safe" is *temendously* hard to judge for a programmer...

Comment: @Marco13: There are a lot of cases where "safe" is really easy for a programmer to judge.  A compiler that sees `extern int foo;` in one header and `extern int *bar;` in another could not assume that `foo` could be cached across accesses to `*bar`, but a programmer who knows what kinds of things `*bar` will point to, and knows that `foo` is not among them, would have no trouble recognizing that such caching was safe.

Comment: @Marco13: BTW, I think the language could be improved by allowing the `register` keyword to be used with global variables and things whose address is taken, provided that (1) if the value of the object is modified during the evaluation of an expression where its address is taken, all accesses must be via pointers derived from the result of that operation; (2) the pointer will cease to be valid after expression evaluation is complete.  Essentially, a compiler could treat the qualifier as an assurance that the object wouldn't be accessed via pointers except when it had no reason to expect it.

Comment: @supercat Although the discussion is interesting (up to the point of which I can claim to "understand" what you're aiming at), it is not really related to this answer (if, at all, then rather to the question), but in any case, beyond what can reasonably be discussed in the comments. Modern languages offer a great toolset, and compilers are tremendously smart. So in most cases, all this is not relevant in terms of performance, and the most "obvious" options that *could* be added to language (to squeeze out the aforementioned 3%) may already be considered by the compiler people anyhow...

Answer (score 2):

Before speed you have to consider correctness. Suppose your upper limit depends on the size of an array and you change that array (add, remove element) inside the loop.
This is to say that it's more "robust" write:

```
for (int i=0; i < n*n+2*n; i++)
```

because you re-evaluate the invariant of the loop. I prefer to profiling if i feel that there is some performance issue.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the ability of the compiler to optimize the computation of the limit, i.e. to perform the same optimization that you were suggesting in code (in general, a compiler will try to perform such trivial optimizations).

If the compiler cannot assert whether the limit changes during loop execution or whether its computation has global side effects, then it cannot perform this optimization. In such a case, if you *know* (at compile time) that in fact there are no side effects and the limit is not changed, then pre-computing the limit is a sensible optimization. Examples:

```
// file foo.cc

extern int non_local_int;               // access can be optimized
extern volatile int volatile_int;       // access must not be optimized
extern int bar(int);                    // may have global side effects
extern void take_addr(int&);            // may store address
namespace {
  int addr_never_taken_int=10;          // never operand of address-of operator
  int addr_taken_int=10;                // used as operand of address-of op.
}

void foo(int n)
{
  for(int i=0; i<n*n+n+n+1; ++i)        // can be optimized 
  { ... }

  int local_int = bar(n);
  for(int i=0; i<n*local_int; ++i)      // can be optimized
  { ... }

  for(int i=0; i<n*non_local_int; ++i)  // can be optimized, but is not threadsafe
  { ... no calls to outside code }

  for(int i=0; i<n*bar(n); ++i)         // cannot be optimized
  { ... }

  for(int i=0; i<addr_never_taken_int; ++i)  // can be optimized
  { ... }

  take_addr(addr_taken_int);
  for(int i=0; i<addr_taken_int; ++i)   // cannot be optimized
  { ... code that calls *any* outside function }

  for(int i=0; i<n*volatile_int; ++i)   // must not be optimized
  { ... }

  for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)                // can be optimized
  { ... code that calls *any* outside function }

  take_addr(n);
  for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)                // cannot be optimized
  { ... code that calls *any* outside function }
}
```

**Edited** to reflect comments made by supercat. Note that [*`volatile` objects are suitable for communication within a single thread of execution (e.g. with a signal handler), but not with another thread*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv). Threadsafety is the responsibility of the programmer.

Comment: The compiler may be able to optimize the loops using `non_local_int` if they do not call any outside code and do not write through any `int*` or `char*` pointers of unknown provenance which might possibly point at `non_local_int`.

Comment: @supercat That would assume that no other thread is changing `non_local_int` during loop execution -- I don't think the compiler can assume that unless you tell it to.

Comment: A compiler which sees a non-`volatile`-qualified write followed by a non-volatile-qualified read of the same storage is allowed to substitute the value written for the value read, and a compiler that sees two non-`volatile`-qualified reads of the same storage is allowed to substitute the results of the first read for the second.  That became true when `volatile` was added to the language, and compilers have been making such substitutions since the early 1990s.  The purpose of `volatile` is to mark places where such substitutions must be forbidden.

Comment: Many compilers will refrain from moving any reads and writes across any `volatile`-qualified access, which should IMHO be the preferred semantics since it allows for the possibility of a volatile flag or control register being used to enable access to shared buffers without requiring that the buffers themselves be in volatile-qualified storage.  Since compilers are allowed to do anything they like if `memcpy` is used on volatile-qualified storage, having `volatile` qualifiers on buffers can substantially impede efficiency compared with limiting qualifiers to access-control flags or registers.

Comment: For the third one, the compiler could only optimize if it could see all the code in the loop; your loop should say something like `...code that can't modify non_local_int directly or indirectly`.  You may also want to have two static variables, one of which has its address taken and one of which never does [make note of the latter restriction in a comment].

Comment: If a static variable never has its address taken, pointer accesses can be assumed never to affect it.  If a variable does have its address taken and exposed to outside code, any pointer which could be have come from or been affected by outside code must be presumed to be capable of identifying it.

Comment: I just made some changes; feel free to edit more if you like.  Compilers are required to be somewhat paranoid when making these optimizations; they have to ensure that there's really no way for the loop limit to change.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the first one is slower than the second one. Because it'll have to calculate the limit in every iteration in the first case whereas in the second case it calculates the limit once at start and then uses it for all the iterations.

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this I always count down to zero or another constant unless the order of operations matters, e.g.

```
for (int i = n*n + 2*n - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{ ... }
```

For me this makes it easier to see how long the loop will take and is less likely to have any 'off by one' errors. In other words the behaviour is fully defined right at the start of loop without worrying if `n` is going to be changed or `i` is going to break out of an array.